# Xamarin.Forms Xaml background Image

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I just started a Xamarin.Forms application and I want to add a background image to my XAML.
I added the attribute but it does not appear when I run it!!
Here is the images.

APP

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new Page();
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App1.Page"
         BackgroundImage="bg.png">
```

[image]

SO, how do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Add your `bg.png` file in each of your native projects, since you are currently using a Android emulator start with your `Xamarin.Android` project:

> Android - Place images in the **Resources/drawable** directory with Build Action: AndroidResource

ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/

Example: In your `Xamarin.Android` project, add `bg.png` as shown:

[image]

Check the `Build Action` of that image and ensure that it is assigned `AndroidResource`. Rebuild and re-test.

Comment: Hello SushiHangover,
I Just did that, and still, does not appear =x

Comment: @Biellx I added some info to my answer, make sure the image is in the correct folder and assigned the correct build action. Clean and rebuild and redeploy to your device/emulator....

Comment: Yeaa, i think the problem is the build action, how do i set the build action to that image?]

Comment: Right click on the image and view properties

Answer (score 5):

In Xamarin.forms

1. The images should be placed in the following folders

   ```
      iOS, Android  - Resources folder 

      Windows/UWP, Windows Phone  - Assets folder
   ```
2. Then the build action(rt click img->properties) of the images should be changed as follows

   ```
   iOS - BundleResource             Windows Phone - Content

   Android - AndroidResource        Windows/UWP - Content
   ```

If Still the image is not displayed, try changing the **Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer** in image Properties

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add background image in XAML file for the entire page in Xamarin project, then use the BackgroundImage property and add your image to the Android project under Resources -> drawable folder and for iOS Resources folder.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneDailerDemo"
             x:Class="PhoneDailerDemo.MainPage"
             BackgroundImage="image3.jpg">

    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <StackLayout Padding="100">
       //..........
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What if i need to reduce the opacity of the image? can i do it dynamically in the app?

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the size of the image worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#embedded-images)) you can achieve this, is by setting the image's build action (in file properties) as Embedded Resource.

Then, using a converter markup-extension you will be able to use it directly in XAML and won't have to copy or link the files in each platform specific project.

Here's the converter you should add to you portable project:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Source))]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
  static readonly Assembly CurrentAssembly = 
    typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetType().Assembly;

  public const string Assets = nameof(Assets);

  public string Source { get; set; }

  public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Source))
      return null;

    // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require            
    var source = $"{CurrentAssembly.GetName().Name}.{Assets}.{Source}";

    var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(source, CurrentAssembly);

    return imageSource;
  }
}
```

Then in your XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorkingWithImages;assembly=WorkingWithImages"
   x:Class="WorkingWithImages.EmbeddedImagesXaml">
  <Image Source="{local:ImageResource Background.jpg}"}
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Image files can be added to each application project and referenced from Xamarin.Forms shared code. To use a single image across all apps, the same filename must be used on every platform, and it should be a valid Android resource name (ie. only lowercase letters, numerals, the underscore, and the period are allowed).

- iOS - Place images in the Resources folder with Build Action: BundleResource . Retina versions of the image should also be supplied - two and three times the resolution with a @2x or @3x suffixes on the filename before the file extension (eg. myimage@2x.png).
- Android - Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build Action: AndroidResource. High- and low-DPI versions of an image can also be supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such as drawable-ldpi , drawable-hdpi , and drawable-xhdpi ).
- Windows Phone - Place images in the application's root directory with Build Action: Content .
- Windows/UWP - Place images in the application's root directory with Build Action: Content .

You can read more at [Working with Images
Loading and displaying images in Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/)